# Computing eigenvector corresponding to dominant eigenvector.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

My question is, why does the eigenvector have to be a unit vector?

Please see the code below, every time the eigenvector is gained after normalization, which I don't understand.[image]

Thank you

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration

Answer (score 1):

An eigenvector doesn't have to be a unit vector.  But in an iterative process such as this, if you don't normalize it you're likely to have your vector either converge to $0$ or "blow up" with norm going to $\infty$, both of which are bad.

Comment: Thanks, I got what you mean, but could you explain to me more about how it will cause the vector goes wrong if I don't normalize it?

Comment: Try it with, say, $A = \pmatrix{2 & 0\cr 0 & 1\cr}$ and you'll see the blow-up.  Or with $A = \pmatrix{.2 & 0\cr 0 & .1\cr}$ and you'll see it go to $0$.